# Unable to understand numpy array additions

Tags: python, arrays, python-3.x, numpy

I am sure that this is a very basic question. However, even after going through several tutorial pages and [the official documentation](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-dev/user/quickstart.html), I am not able to understand the addition logic in numpy arrays. Consider the following for example:

```
In [5]: a = np.array([1, 2, 3])

In [6]: b = np.array([1, 2, 3, 4])

In [7]: a + b
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-7-f96fb8f649b6> in <module>()
----> 1 a + b

ValueError: operands could not be broadcast together with shapes (3,) (4,)
```

This is perfectly fine. Since arrays have different shapes, we don't expect "elementwise" operations to hold. Now consider this:

```
In [12]: np.array([1]) + np.array([1, 2, 3, 4])
Out[12]: array([2, 3, 4, 5])
```

Suddenly, there seems to no problem with different shapes. Also this doesn't look like an "elementwise" operation to me. This seems to hold even in the following case:

```
In [15]: np.array([[1], [2]]) + np.array([1, 2, 3, 4])
Out[15]: 
array([[2, 3, 4, 5],
       [3, 4, 5, 6]])
```

I am unable to understand the logic behind these outputs and errors.

Comment: It's all based on axises and the fact that within each axis of the array with larger axis there shouldn't be more than 1 item. Otherwise, they must be in separate arrays.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're seeing `numpy`'s broadcasting at work.

A `numpy` array that has only a single element will be treated like a scalar. So your second block of code is the same as `1 + np.array([1, 2, 3, 4])`. The `1` (or `np.array([1])`) gets broadcast to the shape of the vector, so it works like `np.array([1,1,1,1])`, and so you add one to each of the other values.

The code in your third block multiplies a column vector (a 2D array where the first dimension is 1) by a row vector, producing a 2D array of the results. Each of the input arrays gets expanded to the dimensions of the other, so the `array([[1],[2]])` has each row stretched, so it works like `array([[1,1,1,1], [2,2,2,2]])` and the `array([1,2,3,4])` row is repeated to become `array([[1,2,3,4],[1,2,3,4]])`. Then the two 2-by-4 arrays are added, elementwise.

Answer (score 1):

This is effectively a scaler plus an array:

```
In [12]: np.array([1]) + np.array([1, 2, 3, 4])
Out[12]: array([2, 3, 4, 5])
```

This is one works because the right hand operand is two single wide rows, and the left hand is a single row:

```
In [15]: np.array([[1], [2]]) + np.array([1, 2, 3, 4])
Out[15]: 
array([[2, 3, 4, 5],
       [3, 4, 5, 6]])
```

These are done through [broadcasting](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/user/basics.broadcasting.html).

Comment: Can you please explain me what do you mean by "op is two single wide columns"?